# Using EXISTS to find rows with Maximum value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why do I get duplication of `Jim` in the results of the following?

```
CREATE TABLE #B (Name VARCHAR(10), Age INT)
INSERT INTO #B 
values 
('Jim', 21),
('Jim', 21),
('Jim', 19),
('Jim', 20),
('Nick', 20),
('Nick', 2),
('Nick', 20);


SELECT  DISTINCT
        Name,
        Age
FROM    #B A
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #B B
        WHERE A.Age > B.Age
              AND A.NAME = B.NAME
        )
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see? Reading that query, it seems logical that you would get Jim twice.

Comment: @AdrianWragg - ok I get it now: aslong as there is an age lower for the same name then that row is returned i.e. it excludes the rows with the minimum ages for each name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the SQL Fiddle shows ([here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee7c6/1)), your query is not doing what you think it is.

Instead of getting the `max()`, it is fetching everything except the minmum.

This version would get the `max()`:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        Name,
        Age
FROM    B A
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT 1
        FROM B B
        WHERE A.Age < B.Age
              AND A.NAME = B.NAME
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you have 2 rows corresponding ?

```
A.Age > B.Age and a.name = b.name
```

so

```
Jim 20 > Jim 19
Jim 21 > Jim 19 
Jim 21 > Jim 20
```

With the distinct, you get `Jim 20 and Jim 21` (as `Jim 21` are merged in one)

**Solution without EXISTS**

```
select Name, Max(Age)
FROM #B
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: +1 thanks - I know that alternative  - but if I take the `DISTINCT` out of query in the `OP` then it can do things that a simple query such as that can't do without adding a sub-query. Hence why I wanted to get my logic right when using `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 and up, then using CTE as described below will give you the max age about every person :

```
drop table #B;
CREATE TABLE #B (Name![enter image description here][1] VARCHAR(10), Age INT)
INSERT INTO #B 
values 
('Jim', 21),
('Jim', 21),
('Jim', 19),
('Jim', 20),
('Nick', 20),
('Nick', 2),
('Nick', 20);

;with cte 
as (select Name, Age, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY Name order by Name desc) as CNT
        from #B
        )
select Name, Age
from cte
where CNT = 1
```

[image]
Results :

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus ...well I actually wanted to know why the EXISTS wasn't working - I wasn't interested in finding an alternative.

Comment: (@kin +1 for putting this forward)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have told to DBMS get all rows where age is lower than maximum age of a person.

You obtain row for Jim 20 and Jim 21.

If you want the max age about every person, you must:

```
SELECT distinct
    Name,
    Age
FROM    #B A
WHERE   not EXISTS
        (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #B B
        WHERE A.Age < B.Age
              AND A.NAME = B.NAME
        )
```

I've added a NOT before EXISTS.

Remain DISTINCT because you have 2 rows (Jim, 21) with the same age